# Retrofit for api with key and parameters - flutter

Tags: flutter, retrofit

Dears,
i need support to understand how to use retrofit in flutter for an api call using url as the following :
$baseUrl$endPoint?key=$key&q=string&days=int

i tried to do it in DIO but i want to do it with retrofit with code generator

Comment: https://medium.com/mindful-engineering/retrofit-the-easiest-way-to-call-rest-apis-is-flutter-fe55d1e7c5c2

please follow this blog.